# Return full string if partial string is found Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to retrieve full string if partially matched.

> Example:
>
> src = 'The expression $ a{\color{blue}{x}}^2 + b{\color{blue}{x}} + c$ is said to be quadratic when TAtrimg001a.svg is \neq 0$'
>
> search for "svg" > should return TAtrimg001a.svg

I am trying to search and find the string "svg". If the "svg" exists then it should return TAtrimg001a.svg not just its location or the word svg itself but the complete svg filename.

In reply to a comment...

I tried finding the match in following differenet ways, but they do really work for my requirment, example:

```
var res = str.match(/svg/ig);
var res = str.search("svg");
var res = str.indexOf( "svg" )
```

Comment: You need to show us how you are matching. Please provide the code with clear requirements. For example, if the filename can contain spaces or not.

Comment: I tried finding this in different ways,
like
var res = str.match(/svg/ig);
var res = str.search("svg");
var res = str.indexOf( "svg" )

Comment: Although this comment is late, here is a solution (example / application), not dissimilar to that offered in the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66571601/1904943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforward with regex. The string `.match` method takes a regex and returns either:

- `null` if there was no match.
- An array otherwise, where the first element is the entire matched string, and the remaining elements are each respective capture group (if any).

So for this case, you just want the whole match, so just taking that first item should be fine. The example regex below just looks for any string of non-whitespace characters that ends with `.svg`. You may want to broaden or tighten that to meet your exact use case.

```js
src = 'The expression $ a{\color{blue}{x}}^2 + b{\color{blue}{x}} + c$ is said to be quadratic when TAtrimg001a.svg is \neq 0$'

function findFileName(str, ext) {
    const match = str.match(new RegExp(`\\w+\\.${ext}`));
    return match && match[0]
}

console.log(findFileName(src, "svg"))
```

*Minor Note: When passing a string to the `RegExp` constructor, backslashes must be doubled, since the first backslash escapes the second as part of the string.*

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can do something like `const result = str.endsWith(".svg") ? str : null;`, which will store in `result` variable full file name (if it ends with ".svg" part, in other words, has `svg` format), or `null` (if it doesn't):

```js
function checkIsFileOfType(str, fileType) {
  return str.endsWith("." + fileType) ? str : null;
}

console.log(checkIsFileOfType("TAtrimg001a.svD", "svg"));
console.log(checkIsFileOfType("TAtrimg001a.svg", "svg"));
```